# Javascript refuses to get value of selected value of a "select" element

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

Thank you in advance for your help! I am relatively new to JS and I am trying to build an "iframe generator" based on a selected width and height. I have the majority of the script working but when trying to grab the selected option of a dropdown, my script is only ever returning the first option value.

I have done quite a bit of research on the subject and found LOTS of answers, but none seem to work for me. You may notice my script has become an amalgamation of JS and Jquery as I have tried to incorporate different ways of getting this to work. I am sure it is some syntax error or something of the like on my own part.

What am I doing wrong??

```
var button = document.getElementById('getCode');
var link = "https://www.google.com";
var width = document.getElementById('width');
var widthType = document.getElementById('widthType');
var widthText = widthType.options[widthType.selectedIndex].text;
var height = document.getElementById('height');
var heightType = document.getElementById('heightType');
var heightText = heightType.options[heightType.selectedIndex].text;

button.onclick = function () {
    var str = '<iframe src="' + link +
        '" width="' + width.value + widthText +
        '" height="' + height.value + heightText +
        '" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>';
    $("#embeddedCode").val(str);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DaddyWarbucks/V89ZC/1/

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can use `$('#width').val()` to get the select value(if width is the select element)

Comment: If you are using jQuery, why use JS to get values for elements?

Comment: also instead of `var widthText = widthType.options[widthType.selectedIndex].text;` you can say `var widthText = $('#widthType option:selected').text();`

Comment: Also I think $('#Width:selected').val()

Comment: also another problem is the `text` need to be read within the on click handler

Comment: I believe I have tried all of these solutions. I will double check each of them. I believe my problem lies in when the script is loaded??

Comment: @Beau did you place your script in a dom ready handler? whether the elements are created dynamically or is it present when the page is loaded? is there any error in your browser console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var link = "https://www.google.com";
//use jQuery event handler
$('#getCode').click(function () {
    //you need to read the selected values & text within the click handler otherwise the variables will always have the intial value, it will not get updated when user changes the selection
    var str = '<iframe src="' + link +
        '" width="' + $('#width').val() + $('#widthType option:selected').text() +
        '" height="' + $('#height').val().value + $('#heightType option:selected').text() +
        '" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>';
    $("#embeddedCode").val(str);
});
```

Comment: "you need to read the selected values & text within the click handler otherwise the variables will always have the intial value, it will not get updated when user changes the selection"   That was the problem! Thank you, your answer not only works but explains my error also.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/V89ZC/2/

```
button.onclick = function () {
    var str = '<iframe src="' + link +
        '" width="' + $("#width").val() + $('#widthType option:selected').text() +
        '" height="' + $("#height").val() + $('#heightType option:selected').text() +
        '" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>';
    $("#embeddedCode").val(str);
};
```

Comment: Boom! Got it. Your answer works, but Arun's answer explains why my solution was not working in the first place. Thank you!

Comment: If you have any other solution other than this, please post it too.